# Level 2 EVSE - Tesla or J1772?

Tags: electric-vehicle

We own two EVs, a Tesla and a Nissan Leaf.  We charge them mostly at home, using a hardwired Level 2 EVSE (which provides high-current 240vac to the actual charger, located in the car).

The Tesla takes a proprietary plug, while the Leaf (and every other EV on the planet) takes a standard J1772 plug.

If I'm going to put in a hard-wired Level 2 EVSE at a new house, should I go with J1772 or Tesla ?

FWIW, due to wiring constraints, the new EVSE will only provide 20 amps (25-amp breaker).

Comment: I imagine you're going to get sick of moving plugs at some point. I would go with a EVSEs that support Power Sharing, so you just plug in both cars and wake up in the morning and find both charged.

Comment: It's the vacation house, so we're very unlikely to have both EVs there at once.  Now that I think of it, the Leaf can't really make it.   We'll almost certainly be in Tesla.   But we're also renting, and like you say, Tesla owners shuld always have that adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I would go J1772, simply because Tesla has a high quality adapter from J1772 included with the cars. But this is honestly mostly an opinion question. If you like having the ability to press the button and open the charge port on the Tesla, maybe the Wall Connector is a better choice. Or you could go with two Wall Connectors, one with J1772, the other with a Tesla connector, and have them do automatic load balancing. It's your call.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "press the button and open the charge port on the Tesla".   We haven't taken delivery yet.  Don't most cars have a button that opens the charge port ?   What does it have to do with whether you're using that adapter, or not ?

Comment: It's a shame this was closed because this is the correct answer.  Plugging a non-Tesla into a Tesla-plug EVSE requires a cheap Chinese adapter that'll burn up your car's port assembly.  Plugging a Tesla into a J1772 involves an adapter *Made By Tesla* so a) it won't fail and b) if it does you'll have warranty repair on everything but the J1772 EVSE.   However **Tesla makes a J1772 EVSE that includes Power Sharing**, it's the Wall Connecto 3.0 with a J1772 socket on it.

Comment: No idea what the powers didn't like about this.  Maybe it sounded like a religious discussion, except as I said, we own both Tesla and non-Tesla.   Oh well.  Thanks (as always) for the very helpful answer.   So looks like this Tesla J1772 just requires you to use the Tesla adapter - I was hoping maybe it had both.  Also, you there's no charge setting between 16 and 24 amps (20 and 30 amp breaker); which, per our earlier discussion, 20/25 is the sweet spot for me.  So I think I'm going to go with that Emporia unit (mentioned in the earlier discussion.  It's also quite a bit cheaper.

Comment: https://shop.emporiaenergy.com/collections/ev-chargers/products/emporia-ev-charger-black-energy-star-ul-listed-48-amp-24-cable-22-nema-14-50?_gl=1*yqwl5c*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxbefBhDfARIsAL4XLRq4FHonWLdrdT3roihAq02WxpWE_pXB1KA8JZJ37-P-eS-RJh4-FE4aAqFuEALw_wcB

Comment: @RustyShackleford your question is opinion-based. We're pretty trigger happy on that here. As to a button to open the port, all cars have a button inside the car. The Tesla charger though has a button on the charge handle that opens the port on the car, which is super handy.

Comment: Also it's a shame they dropped the 25A setting. The first and second generation units had one.

Comment: Well, I found out what I needed to know (that the adapter, that lets you charge non-Tesla on Tesla Level 2, sucks.